# When You Take Damage Does Your END DM Change?

Tags: combat, damage, mongoose-traveller-2

On page 74, we learn that:

> Damage is initially applied to a target’s END. If a target is reduced to 0 END, then any excess damage is deducted from the target’s STR or DEX (target’s choice of which).

There is nothing that says your END DM is changed when you take damage. However, in the psionics chapter on page 196, it says that:

> Using a psionic talent costs a number of PSI points, temporarily reducing the Traveller’s total. As the characteristic DM for all psionic skill checks is determined by the Travellers’ current PSI total, it gets harder and harder to use powers as the Traveller’s PSI declines.

Since damage is temporarily reducing your END (and possibly STR/DEX) does that also mean the DM is modified? Or is the 'use the current characteristic total' rule only applicable to PSI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my game we have used current stat value for all rolls. It feels natural that a character gets less bonuses the more hurt he is.

Page 79 (natural healing) backs up this claim: "A Traveller who requires surgery only regains characteristic points equal to his END DM per day of rest, which means that the Traveller may never heal naturally and will even get worse if his END DM is currently negative (and it probably will be…)."

Comment: Page 79 (natural healing) backs up this claim: "*A Traveller who requires surgery only regains characteristic points equal to his END DM per day of rest, which means that the Traveller may never heal naturally and will even get worse if his END DM is currently negative (and it probably will be…).*"

Comment: I'm going to copy Chrisophers comment into the answer to improve it. A great source.